# Why material icon doesn't display if I reference local svg file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I need to change dynamically the value of md-icon that is why I am trying to reference local svg icon. But the icon doesn't display on my page. What am I missing. Thank you in advance for your time. I also created pluker but I didn't know how to add the image folder with the svg file: 
I am getting the folowing error: angular.js:11756 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/documents/Website/QuizTest10/Images/Icons/star.svg. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

https://plnkr.co/edit/HK1uftFkIoAUy92U1iuy?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>

    <script     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js">  </script>
    <script   src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.3/angular-material.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    <body>
       <div ng-controller="test">
           <md-button class="md-fab md-mini md-primary">
           <md-icon class="material-icons" aria-label="Done">star_border</md-icon>
           </md-button>

           <!-- Doesnt work even if I add the icon in the Image folder-->
           <md-button class="md-fab md-primary" md-theme="cyan" aria-label="Profile">
           <md-icon icon="/Images/star.svg" style="width: 24px; height: 24px;">        </md-icon>
           </md-button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should `/Images/star.svg` be `./Images/star.svg`? Is your `Images` folder located at the root of your file system?

Comment: I tried that as well. I added the error that I am getting to the top

Comment: if you are running your app via localhost, try `Images/star.svg`

Comment: Thank you I tried this as well, Didn't work. The same error.

Comment: You are running this app on a web server? Your plunkr works fine

Comment: How can I run it to be able to see it?